# download with php script - .rar becomes .rar.html on mac

Tags: php, download

i start my downloads with a php script, it's very simple and looks like this:

```
$dir = 'downloads/';
$type = 'application/x-rar-compressed, application/octet-stream, application/zip';

function makeDownload($file, $dir, $type) 
{   
    header("Content-Type: $type");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$file\"");
    readfile($dir.$file);
}

if(!empty($_GET['file']) && !preg_match('=/=', $_GET['file'])) {
    if(file_exists ($dir.$_GET['file']))     {
        makeDownload($_GET['file'], $dir, $type);
    }

}
```

It works fine on win7 + ff/opera/chrome/safari, but on MAC it tries to download file.rar.html or file.zip.html instead of file.rar/file.zip.

Any ideas why?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"application/x-rar-compressed, application/octet-stream, application/zip" is not a valid file type. You need to add logic in your script to detect the type of file, then offer a specific file type. Example (untested):

```
<?php
$dir = 'downloads/';

function makeDownload($file, $dir) 
{   
    switch(strtolower(end(explode(".", $file)))) {
      case "zip": $type = "application/zip"; break;
      case "rar": $type = "application/x-rar-compressed"; break;
      default: $type = "application/octet-stream";
    }
    header("Content-Type: $type");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$file\"");
    readfile($dir.$file);
    exit; // you should exit here to prevent the file from becoming corrupted if anything else gets echo'd after this function was called.
}

if(!empty($_GET['file']) && !preg_match('=/=', $_GET['file'])) {
    if(file_exists ($dir.$_GET['file']))     {
        makeDownload($_GET['file'], $dir);
    }

}
?>
```